# Is there an easy way to make it work

Tags: c++

ALL,

```
const std::string foo[] = {
    if( <my_condition> )
        "Test0",
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
};
```

I'm trying to make it work and not to repeat the code.

Is there a simple solution?

TIA!

Comment: You're going to need to explain this better.

Comment: Explain in English what this is supposed to be doing, that does not make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a shot at answering, but you should really edit your question to be more specific.

If you intend to have the array `const`, you must decide the initialization values at compile time.
This means your condition must also be evaluated at compile time.

One route you can take to accomplish this is through a macro:

```
#define CONDITION false

const std::string foo[] = {
    #if CONDITION
        "Test0",
    #endif
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
};
```

Alternatively,
you may want to consider using `std::vector<std::string>` and building the list at run time.

Comment: ...ooor take a `std::vector<std::string>` and try to make it a `constexpr`.